# Lipschitz continuity and $l^1$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a function defind as follows:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
  x,        & \|x\| \leq 1 \\ 
  x/ \|x\|, & \|x\| > 1 \end{cases}
$$
where $\| \cdot \|$ is the $l^1$ norm.

Then it can be shown, that $\|f(x) - f(y)\| \leq 2\|x-y\|$. I need to prove, that $2$ cannot be improved. How can I do that?

Comment: When proving inequalities are sharp, simply find a pair $x,y$ such that the inequality is an _equality_.

Comment: @DKS yes, I tried, but did not find any. That is why I have posted this question

Comment: What are the little inequalities you use to prove the given inequality? They might give you some clue to find the equality.

Comment: @iamvegan It was my first [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952642/show-that-fx-fy-leq-2-x-y). Unfortunately, I see no clue.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952642/show-that-fx-fy-leq-2-x-y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider for $0 < \varepsilon$ the points $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (1, \varepsilon)$. Then $\lVert x-y\rVert = \varepsilon$, and we have $f(x) = x$, $f(y) = \frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}y$, so

$$\lVert f(x) - f(y)\rVert = \biggl\lvert 1 - \frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}\biggr\rvert + \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} = \frac{2\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} = \frac{2}{1+\varepsilon}\lVert x-y\rVert.$$

Comment: It is beautiful! How did you notice this?

Comment: Looking at the map at large, it looks like nothing bad can happen if both points are far away from the origin. So one is led to look at the behaviour near the boundary of the unit "ball". Taking one point on the boundary is a natural first approach. Then taking a vertex gives the example. In other words, an educated guess as to where to look, and guessing correctly.

Comment: Now a new question arose: is it true for inner product or Hilbert spaces (that 2 cannot be improved)?

Comment: No, in Hilbert spaces the projection to a closed convex set (like for example the closed unit ball) never increases distances (so $1$ is always a Lipschitz constant for such a projection, it's the best unless the set consists of a single point [when $0$ is also a Lipschitz constant]).